# Function isn't printing out values

Tags: python

```
def T(n):
  if n == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
    
print (T(2))
```

I want to print out a list of numbers from the recurrence relation shown above, but it's not really printing them out and shows an error. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The error I'm getting is a recursion error.

Comment: In this example n is never equal to 0 so it reaches maximum recursion depth and throws an error. Maybe you'd want `n<=0`?

Comment: If you're getting an error, include that in your question.

Comment: @JimStewart Alright, just give me a minute..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you might want to change your function to this to avoid unnecesssary loop

```
def T(n):
  if n <= 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return T(n-1) + (n-1) * T(n-2)
    
T(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not printing anything. You're calling the function and discarding the result.

```
print(T(2))
```

Comment: Yup, I tried that. it's showing a recursion error now...